# How can I use a regex to search a PDF for all words within parentheses EXCEPT for a specific set of words?

Tags: python, regex, regex-negation, findall

I am trying to search through an 8-page PDF file for all words within parentheses EXCEPT for "(EAI), (EY)" and a few others. I am using a regex and can get all say three letter words within parentheses to pull, but I don't know how to exclude what I want to exclude.

```
import re
lines = text.split()
search = "\(\D{3}\)"
regex = re.compile(search)

for line in lines:
    three_letters= regex.findall(line)
    for word in three_letters:
    print(word)
```

I get the following list:

(FBS)
(NFS)
(IAD)
(CDs)
(CDs)
(EAI)
(EAI)
(EAI)
(VIG)
(EAI)
(EAI)
(NTF)
(DRP)
(EAI)
(IAD)

But I need a handful of them excluded.

I've been banging my head on this one for a while please help!!

Answer (score 2):

Use the findall function with this (matches 3 letters)

`\((?!(?:list|of|stuff|you|don't|want)\))[A-Z]{3}\)`

Formatted

```
 \(
 (?!
      (?:
           list
        |  of
        |  stuff
        |  you
        |  don't
        |  want 
      )
      \)
 )
 [A-Z]{3} 
 \)
```

---

Specify a range to make it variable.
This example matches 2 to 5 letters `{2,5}`.
Or, 2 to no upper limit is just `{2,}`

`\((?!(?:list|of|stuff|you|don't|want)\))[A-Z]{2,5}\)`

Comment: What is the purpose of the first `'\)'` sequence?

Comment: @snakecharmerb - I assume you mean `(?:list|of|stuff|you|don't|want)\)`<-_**HERE**_. The `\)` is a boundary condition which allows stuff like `wanted` or `often` to pass. Do you understand ?

Comment: @sin Thanks for replying.  What confuses me is that the escaped (?) brackets don't balance - there is one '\(` but two '\)' - what am I missing?

Comment: @snakecharmerb - You've lost me. Obviously the regex is balanced. So, lets see what you could mean. There is a total of 1 `\(` construct. And there are 2 `\)` constructs. Is that what you mean ?

Comment: @snakecharmerb - Here is a conceptual example, this  `\( (?=\)) (?=\)) (?=\)) (?=\)) (?=\)) (?=\)) (?=\)) (?=\)) (?=\)) (?=\)) (?=\)) \)` will match only `()` and that's it. In other words the assertion is just looking at the end `\)` and not matching it. It is matching it but only within the assertion. It is not consumed as a global match. Doesn't matter to the regex of course, you can match a hundred `\)` in a row, it don't matter.

Comment: Note that if the OP decides to allow parenthesis `[A-Z()]` as a character in the content, then it would probably have to be balanced.